# How can I use QueryDSL on multiple mongo repositories?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-mongodb, querydsl

I am building a profile service with the typical REST endpoints for creating, reading, updating and deleting profiles. For this I am using the Spring Framework together with a MongoDB. On top I would like to use QueryDSL to create some custom queries.

A full minimal working example of the current implementation can be found here: https://github.com/mirrom/profile-modules

I would like to have sub profile models that extend the base profile model, and sub sub models that extend the sub models. By this I have hierarchical profiles that inherit the fields of its parent profile. The idea is to store all profiles in the same collection and distinguish them via the automatically created `_class` field.

A simple example (with Lombok annotations):

```
@Data
@Document(collection = "profiles")
@Entity
public class Profile {
    
    @Id
    private ObjectId id;
    
    @Indexed
    private String title;
    
    @Indexed
    private String description;
    
    private LocalDateTime createdAt;
    
    private LocalDateTime modifiedAt;
    
}
```

```
@Data
@Entity
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class Sub1Profile extends Profile {
    
    private String sub1String;
    
    private int sub1Integer;
    
}
```

While (all) profiles can get accessed via the endpoint `/api/v1/profiles`, the sub1Profiles can be accessed via `/api/v1/profiles/sub-1-profiles`. Currently the sub1Profiles endpoint delivers all profiles, but it should just deliver the sub1Profiles and its children. For this I would like to use QueryDSL, but I can't add `QuerydslPredicateExecutor<Profile>` and `QuerydslBinderCustomizer<QProfile>` to more than one repository interface. This is how my profile repository looks like:

```
@Repository
public interface ProfileRepository extends MongoRepository<Profile, ObjectId>, QuerydslPredicateExecutor<Profile>,
        QuerydslBinderCustomizer<QProfile> {
    
    @Override
    default void customize(QuerydslBindings bindings, QProfile root) {
        
        bindings.bind(String.class)
                .first((SingleValueBinding<StringPath, String>) StringExpression::containsIgnoreCase);
    }
    
}
```

If I now try to do the same with Sub1ProfileRepository:

```
@Repository
public interface Sub1ProfileRepository
        extends MongoRepository<Sub1Profile, ObjectId>, QuerydslPredicateExecutor<Sub1Profile>,
        QuerydslBinderCustomizer<QSub1Profile> {
    
    default void customize(QuerydslBindings bindings, QProfile root) {
        
        bindings.bind(String.class)
                .first((SingleValueBinding<StringPath, String>) StringExpression::containsIgnoreCase);
    }
    
}
```

I get this error message:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sub1ProfileRepository' defined in com.example.profile.repository.sub1profile.Sub1ProfileRepository defined in @EnableMongoRepositories declared on MongoRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableMongoRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property customize found for type Sub1Profile!

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you connecting to diff databases?

Comment: @zatef No, it is one database with only one collection. All profiles should be stored in this single collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Sub1ProfileRepository`'s `customize` method, you have used `QProfile` as method argument. Can you use `QSub1Profile` instead and check if it's working?